# Javascript library, or jquery plugin to create swipe-based carousel in mobile safari / ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch, swipe

Have you seen yahoo's ipad/tablet home page? The swipe effect for flipping through headlines is impressive. I have seen some workarounds in jquery (using the cycle plugin + the touchwipe plugin) but these all simply detect user gesture and then run the x- absolute position animation, rather than actually track the user's gesture. Know of a solution similar to yahoo's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Used the "snap-to" option to re-create the carousel effect.

Comment: The author of iScroll, @cubiq, has a new library SwipeView for just this purpopse: http://cubiq.org/swipeview

Answer (score 1):

Swipe JS is a good one. If this is the effect that you are looking for - http://swipejs.com

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but there is [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: As far as I see, jQuery Mobile 0.9 doesnt support swiping carousels yet. See [https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/296](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/296)